# React js: add availability (time slots)

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I am new to react and I want  to add the functionality to add Available Times save them to the database then fetch them.. However, I am not sure which library to use as most of them don't provide much documentation. Here are the options that I ve found so far:

```
https://github.com/trotzig/react-available-times
https://www.npmjs.com/package/scheduler-calendar
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-availability-calendar
```

Any help is much appreciated thank u

Comment: try using bootstrap components

Answer (score 0):

Weekly downloads count on npmjs.com can give you a hint which one to pick.